# Import .owl file in Semantic Media Wiki

Tags: owl, ontology, semantic-mediawiki, protege4

Has anyone imported a .owl file in semantic media wiki?
What options do I have for that.
(There is an extension RDFIO however that does not work for .owl files).

Comment: Try asking at this maillist: semediawiki-user@lists.sourceforge.net.